# Return first attribute of an element from XML

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, xquery

Consider an XML element as

```
<Person>
    <contact phone="123" email="abc" address="abcde">Sid</contact>
    <contact phone="987" email="cba" address="qwerty">Zid</contact>
</Person>
```

I want an xpath which will print the contact node which has the first attribute="123" regardless of the attribute name. something like /Person/contact[@*[position()=1]="123"]. In this case, it should print "Sid".

Comment: As Martin pointed out, what you're asking for is not defined in the XPath data model. The "first attribute" is not a thing that XPath claims to be able to deliver. Your XPath implementation might have `email` as the "first" attribute on one `contact` element, and `address` as the "first" attribute on the other. To get a reliable solution, you'll need to come up with different criteria for which attribute you need to look at. "First in alphabetical order of attribute name" would be well-defined, though it would be harder to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `/contact/@*[1]` you might get what you want. Remember however that attributes are not ordered (respectively ["The relative order of attribute nodes is implementation-dependent."](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model)) so different implementations might return a different attribute for a positional predicate `[1]` on `@*`.

The XPath `/Person/contact[@* = '123']` might address your edited requirement, as it selects a `contact` element which has any attribute with value `'123'`. As already pointed out, you can also use a positional predicate `/Person/contact[@*[1] = '123']` but the result can be implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Appreciate it. 

I've updated my question - would you be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're aware of possible problem caused by relying your logic on *order of attribute* as mentioned by Martin Honnen, but still want to go this way, you can try the following :

```
/Person/contact[@*[1][.='123']]
```

above XPath select `<contact>` elements having first attribute value equals `123`, regardless of the attribute name.